# Java Media Framework MP3 plugin

Tags: java, encoding, mp3, jmf, decoding

I am looking for a library that can encode/decode mp3 files. I want to write a program that can change the bit rate of mp3 files.

Does anyone know if the JMF MP3 plugin from Oracle do this job. Here is its link:
[JMF MP3 plugin](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html)

Answer (score 4):

The [mp3plugin.jar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5B9wDXIGw9lRmpSbEUtenljd1k/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-miuzcGB8fsXn2EQh3sVolA) of JMF is an SPI for **decoding** MP3.  It does not provide an SPI for encoding.

Comment: So as I understand I cannot use this library to change the bit rate of MP3 files. Is that correct?